# ng-repeat does not work with mongoldb data

Tags: angularjs, mongodb

this is my angular code

```
function load_interest(){
    console.log("in angular");
    $http.get('http://localhost:3000/interest').success(function(data){
    console.log("and"); 
    console.log(data.interest);
        $scope.interests=data;                  
});
};
```

This is my html code:

```
<div  ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="orderCtrl">   
   <table class="table table-striped">
     <tbody ng-repeat="inter in interests">
       <tr>
         <td><li>{{ inter.interest}}</li></td>
       </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

this is my data:

```
  { _id: '56371e0b2c456955b041b278',
    username: 'mamba@gmail.com',
    interest: 'cricket' 
  }, { 
    _id: '56371e3f2c456955b041b279',
    username: 'mamba@gmail.com',
    interest: 'cricket'
  }, { 
    _id: '56371e7c2c456955b041b27a',
    username: 'mamba@gmail.com',
    interest: 'cricket' 
  },
```

this method had worked earlier with a mySQL database. Could someone please help me? I am new to Mongodb.

With out ng repeat when i use {{interest}} i can see the entire data 
[{"_id":"56371e0b2c456955b041b278","username":"mamba@gmail.com","interest":"cricket"},{"_id":"56371e3f2c456955b041b279","username":"mamba@gmail.com","interest":"cricket"},{"_id":"56371e7c2c456955b041b27a","username":"mamba@gmail.com","interest":"cricket"},{"_id":"56371ec92c456955b041b27b","username":"mamba@gmail.com","interest":"cricket"},{"_id":"56371ed82c456955b041b27c","username":"mamba@gmail.com","interest":"cricket"},{"_id":"56371ee32c456955b041b27d","username":"mamba@gmail.com","interest":"cricket"},{"_id":"563979d38e40c191ff91e338","username":"mamba@gmail.com","interest":"basketball"}]

Comment: keep your data in array then it will work

Answer (score 0):

Either change your html to this:

```
 <tbody ng-repeat="inter in interests.data"> ...
```

Or keep the html as it is but change the controller to this

```
 $scope.interests = data.interests;
```

Otherwise your ng-repear does not loop over interests but over the data object.

And yes, the `data.interests` should be an array :)

Comment: when i do console.log(data.interest); in my angular page. It shows data as undefined. any idea y is this happening?

Comment: maybe a typo? what if you try just `console.log(data);` ?

Comment: I tried what u said but its not working. some how the control is not going to the inter.interest line because now the <li> tags dot is also not visible on my page

Comment: yes when i do console.log(data) i can see the list of objects like this [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the demo http://dojo.telerik.com/ujirI

```
 $scope.interests = [];
 $scope.interests.push({
 _id: '56371e0b2c456955b041b278',
 username: 'mamba@gmail.com',
 interest: 'cricket'
 }, {
_id: '56371e3f2c456955b041b279',
 username: 'mamba@gmail.com',
 interest: 'cricket'
 }, {
_id: '56371e7c2c456955b041b27a',
 username: 'mamba@gmail.com',
 interest: 'cricket'
});
```

hope this may help you

Comment: could i do this  $scope.interests.push(data);  ??

Comment: no its method and assignment will not allowed you can use  $scope.interests.push(data)